# WordPress settings API with tabs - options save only for an active tab

Tags: plugin-development

The problem is that whenever I activate tab and save options, all settings in the active tab remain as they are, but settings in other tabs reset to defaults. If possible, I would like to keep the settings together as `eswc_settingz` on a database. I present the code with only 2 tabs for better clarity:

```php
// Create settings class.
class extra_settings_settings {

    private $options;
    private $settings_page_name;
    private $settings_menu_name;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->settings_page_name = 'woo-extra-settings';
        $this->settings_menu_name = 'Woo Extra Settings';   

        // Initialize and register settings. 
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'register_settings' ) );
        // Add settings page.
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_settings_page' ) );
        // Add settings link to plugins page.
        add_action( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), array( $this, 'add_settings_link' ) );
    }

    public function register_settings() {

        register_setting( 'eswc_settingz', 'eswc_settingz', array( $this, 'sanitize' ) );

        // ID / title / callback / page
        add_settings_section( 'general_section', null, array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), $this->settings_page_name );
        add_settings_section( 'account_section', null, array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), $this->settings_page_name );

        // ID / title / callback / page / section /args
        add_settings_field( 'eswc_kill_gutenberg', __( 'Gutenberg', 'woo-extra-settings' ), array( $this, 'eswc_kill_gutenberg_callback' ), $this->settings_page_name, 'general_section' );
        add_settings_field( 'eswc_change_email_author', __( 'WP core email author', 'woo-extra-settings' ), array( $this, 'eswc_change_email_author_callback' ), $this->settings_page_name, 'general_section' );
        add_settings_field( 'eswc_redirect', __( 'Login redirect', 'woo-extra-settings' ), array( $this, 'eswc_redirect_callback' ), $this->settings_page_name, 'account_section' );

    }

    public function add_settings_page() {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Settings Admin', $this->settings_menu_name, 'manage_options', $this->settings_page_name, array( $this, 'create_settings_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the option that is saved or the default.
     *
     * @param string $index. The option we want to get.
     */
    public function eswc_get_settings( $index = false ) {

        $defaults = array ( 'eswc_kill_gutenberg' => false, 'eswc_change_email_author' => false, 'eswc_redirect' => false);
        $settings = get_option( 'eswc_settingz', $defaults );

        if ( $index && isset( $settings[ $index ] ) ) {
            return $settings[ $index ];
        }

        return $settings;
    }

    public function create_settings_page() {

        $this->options = $this->eswc_get_settings();        

        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>Woo Extra Settings</h1>
            <?php
            $active_tab = isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'tab' ] : 'general';         
            ?>
            <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
                <a href="?page=woo-extra-settings&tab=general" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'general' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">General</a>
                <a href="?page=woo-extra-settings&tab=account" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'account' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Account</a>
            </h2>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // Output nonce, action, and option_page fields for a settings page.
                 if( $active_tab == 'general' ) {
                    settings_fields( 'eswc_settingz' );             
                    echo '<table class="form-table">';
                    do_settings_fields ($this->settings_page_name, 'general_section');
                    echo '</table>';
                } else if ( $active_tab == 'account' ){
                    settings_fields( 'eswc_settingz' );             
                    echo '<table class="form-table">';
                    do_settings_fields ($this->settings_page_name, 'account_section');
                    echo '</table>';
                }

                submit_button();
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
```